# My raspberry pi is upgrading for like 2,5 hrs and it is stuck at 57% but still removing some files.Is this normal?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, update

enter image description here
Removing 'diversion of /boot/overlays
[image: while upgrading it still removing files but stuck at 57% for an hour]

Comment: Start another terminal and check logs and `dmesg` to see if there's something bad happening with the storage drive, or perhaps `top` to see if the CPU is struggling, you know, basic diagnostics

Comment: It should take 5-10 minutes. If it is taking this long there is probably a problem with the SD Card. Let it finish no matter how long it takes but you should get a new Card. It depends on what it is doing. The download can take a very long time but once it starts installing should not take long.

Answer (score 0):

At this point it would be 12 hours if still stuck, lol.  Anyway: Just do a normal shutdown; the system will kill whatever processes, and there is a good chancee apt will recover from this if it was just some network glitch.  Which it is unusual, but I think periodically I have seen it getting tangled up in a similar manner before.

*Before* you shutdown though, add `fsck.mode=force` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`, making sure that file is all one line (ie., just leave a space between this and the end of the current line).  Also check that `fsck.repair=yes` is there and if not, add that too.

When you reboot, try the update again.  If it does the same thing, update your question with that information, including whether you noticed fsck taking more than a minute or posting unusual messages at boot.

If all is well you can then remove the `fsck.mode=force`.